# Use a library to create installable triggers for Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My customer has ~150 Google spreadsheets, one each for their "vendors". The spreadsheets are based on a template spreadsheet, in which, I've setup triggers for custom functions. However, when the template is copied and setup as a new vendor spreadsheet, the triggers are lost.

I've written a library shared with the spreadsheets to consolidate code. I've been trying to add a way to install the triggers (using the library) in the spreadsheets once they're opened to correct their absence when copied from the template, however, I'm not having any success. I believe it may not be possible for a library to create installable triggers for anything but itself.

With a library referenced as "SheetNames", properly linked and functioning, I have this in each spreadsheet:

```
function onOpen(){
  SheetNames.manageTimers();
}
```

In the library "SheetNames", I have this code:

```
function deleteAllTriggers(workbook) {
  // Loop over all triggers and delete them
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(workbook);
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
  }
}

function manageTimers(){
  // code to install timers if not present
  // and remove them from terminated vendors' sheets named "Vendor 2xxx..."
  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var workbookName = workbook.getName();

  //Assumes workbookName is formatted as "Vendor XXXX..."
  var vendorNumber = ""+workbookName.substr(7, 256);
  if ((vendorNumber.length >= 4) && (vendorNumber.substr(0,1) == "2")) {
    //this is a 2xxx vendor and all timers need to be deleted
    Logger.log("Deleted all timers for "+workbookName);
    deleteAllTriggers(workbook);
    return;
  }

  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(workbook);
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    if (allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "maintenance") {

      //delete old version of trigger if not timeBased
      if (allTriggers[i].getEventType()=="CLOCK") {
        var maintexists=1;
      } else {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
      }
    }

    if (allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "incrementDummyValueToForceUpdate") {

     //delete old version of trigger if not timeBased
      if (allTriggers[i].getEventType()=="CLOCK") {
        var counterexists=1;
      } else {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  //create triggers if they don't exist
  if (!maintexists) {    
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('maintenance')
      .forSpreadsheet(workbook)
      .timeBased()
      .onMonthDay(27)
      .create();
  }

  if (!counterexists) {    
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('incrementDummyValueToForceUpdate')
      .forSpreadsheet(workbook)
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(5)
      .create();
  }
}
```

Specifically, the code chokes on `.timeBased()` with the error `TypeError: Cannot find function timeBased in object SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder. (line 104, file "Sheets", project`

That seems appropriate as the `.forSpreadsheet()` argument seems to only work with `onOpen`, `onEdit`, `onChange`, etc.

If I change references from

```
var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(workbook);
```

to

```
var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
```

and change this

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('incrementDummyValueToForceUpdate')
  .forSpreadsheet(workbook)
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(5)
  .create();
```

to this

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('incrementDummyValueToForceUpdate')
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(5)
  .create();
```

then put the code into each spreadsheet manually, it works fine, but that defeats the purpose of the library. If I put the changed code into the library, it creates triggers in the library itself, which isn't what I need.

So, basically, I'm looking for a solution on how to create installable triggers using a library, so that I don't have to copy all of this code to hundreds of spreadsheets, or setup the triggers manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I put the changed code into the library, it creates triggers in the library itself, which isn't what I need.

Turns out that bit isn't correct, and adding a trigger via a library creates the trigger in the sheet itself. Example code:

```
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('maintenance')
  .timeBased()
  .onMonthDay(27)
  .create();
```

Comment: can you call `maintenance`from the active spreadsheet even if the function is inside the library?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this code, but I believe the answer is yes, as that was the point of consolidating all of the code into a library.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use:  `.forSpreadsheet(workbook)` to create a time based trigger.

It must be:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('incrementDummyValueToForceUpdate')
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(5)
  .create();
```

I'm not sure if the function `incrementDummyValueToForceUpdate` can access the active spreadsheet.  In an add-on it can, but you aren't using an add-on.

You could publish an add-on, and have the customer use the add-on in every spreadsheet.  If you don't want to do that and each spreadsheet has a bound project, there is a way to programatically update bound projects.

Just yesterday, the new Apps Script API was announced.  You would need to update a project.  See "Update project content"

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-projects

Comment: Regarding `.forSpreadsheet(workbook)`, I know. I did state that in my overly long post, so np if you missed it. `incrementDummyValueToForceUpdate` can access the active spreadsheet, as it's a library function, but adding it to a timer in the library is useless, as it will error out due to no sheets bound to the library. The triggers have to be in the spreadsheets (as best I can figure out) for things to work. If add-ons can manage triggers then I supposed that could be a route. I have not investigated add-ons that much. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't give any information about this kind of thing.  I wish I had an exact answer, but I'm not sure.  My incomplete knowledge about the time based triggers comes from "trial and error."  If you do find out that add-on code behaves differently for a time-based trigger than a library does, it's good to answer your own question, if no one else does.

Comment: The documentation isn't setup very well, IMO. I'm not sure I"m going to go with the add-on route. I've just resigned myself to putting the installable trigger code in each sheet, just to get done with it. Thanks!